# How to remove gap between Grid columns in XAML (Windows Store app)

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm building a UI in XAML for a Windows Store app; it uses two background graphics in adjacent columns.  The XAML is as follows:

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="11" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="/Assets/stop-title-background-strip.png" Stretch="Fill" />
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="/Assets/routes-chevron.png" Stretch="Fill" />
            <TextBlock Text="Available Routes" />
        </Grid>
```

However, when this is rendered, there is an obvious tiny gap between the columns:

[image]

I've tried setting the UseLayoutRounding attribute of the Grid and Image elements to "true"  (and false) but this doesn't fix the problem.

How can I stop this gap appearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use negative values for one or more of your images. Normally it is not recommended, but this seems like a good enough exception. You'd need to do something like

```
<Image
    Source="/Assets/stop-title-background-strip.png"
    Stretch="Fill" />
<Image
    Grid.Column="1"
    Source="/Assets/routes-chevron.png"
    Stretch="Fill"
    Margin="-20,0,0,0" />
```

or

```
<Image
    Source="/Assets/stop-title-background-strip.png"
    Stretch="Fill"
    Margin="0,0,-20,0" />
<Image
    Grid.Column="1"
    Source="/Assets/routes-chevron.png"
    Stretch="Fill" />
```

Comment: Yes, negative values for the margins solved the problem.  I'd be interested to know if there is a less brute-force approach to this, akin to turning off Layout Rounding in WPF.  If nobody comes up with anything I'll gladly mark this as the answer.

Comment: Layout rounding merely says whether controls should snap to pixels vs. subpixel positioning. Additionally you could use [Image.NineGrid](http://blog.xyzzer.me/2011/09/21/image-ninegrid-in-winrt/) so the overlapping parts don't stretch while the background part can be just 1 pixel wide and will stretch to required size.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Margin` to 0 between columns.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem today, and overlapping the cells with negative margins was no option - the content of the cells had alpha values, and overlapping would have rendered strange results.

After hours of investigation I found the reason for the gaps and corrected them, but it's incredible that the solution has to be like this, that is what I would expect from the UI framework to handle.

Anyway, this is the solution I found:

**The problem apparently is that the way device-independent pixels are treated is not always right when using `Grids`** - certain combinations of row heights, column widths, grid x and y position values do result in rounding errors that lead to the gaps. Probably this won't occur when the grid's position and size are completely dynamic and set in XAML, but that's not possible in all cases.

So the solution is to **ensure that all the above values are set to perfect device pixels** instead of just any double value one might calculate. I used the following function to accomplish this for all relevant values, and all gaps are gone:

```
private double RoundToDevicePixels(double originalValue)
{
    double dpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
    double dpiFactor = (96.0 / dpi);
    int xDpi = (int)(originalValue * dpiFactor);
    return xDpi / dpiFactor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a little late but still I hope it can help.

Set `UseLayoutRounding`in the grid to false.

`UseLayoutRounding` set to false:

[image: UseLayoutRounding set to false]

`UseLayoutRounding` not set (default true):

[image: UseLayoutRounding not set or default true]